# Combining large number of small files for mapreduce input

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop & MapReduce .We are developing a network monitoring tool (in java).We collect various information of monitored devices periodically , say in every 5 sec. and write that information to HDFS through java client each information as new file(since we'r not using hdfs append facility).In HDFS our data organization would be like this:

```
/monitored_info
      /f1.txt
      /f2.txt
      .......
      /f1020010.txt
```

Thus each file typically less than 2KB in size.
I know each map task can take upto  1 file, and it will spawn as much as map task and the job will be inefficient. To get rid of this we used merging facility of FileUtil before submitting job:

```
FileUtil.copyMerge(fileSystem, new Path("monitored_info"), fileSystem,
                new Path("mapInputfile"), false, conf, null);
```

Is it a good practice ? Or is there any other mechanism used for such requirements? Please help...

Comment: wouldn't be possible to merge small files before entering hadoop? If you don't need some immediate data processing it seems to be more reasonable ...

Comment: Can we use append functionality? I used hadoop-1.0.4 and it is not supproting this.

Comment: well, Hive can append (not sure about Hbase). My suggestion was - if you don't need process data immediately (e.g. once per 6 hour is ok), then I'd put data for some time (e.g. 1 hour) into one file and then put it to HDFS. In other words, I'd prepare bigger file on a separate computer and then move them to hadoop

Comment: it is fine. you mean biggger file  = i block size ?, Then can we reduce default block size. Is there any performance hit?

Comment: Tom, I'm not talking about hadoop at all! Before inserting data into hdfs, I would collect them into one bigger file (e.g. create 1 file with 2 hours sensor data). And when this bigger file is created - put it into hadoop(hdfs).

Comment: Agreed with @xhudik . You should be able to aggregate your records on your local file system and move to hdfs after some period. Consider this scenario: **1)** transfer logs to a new file,  **2)** aggregate those records on that file,   **3)** send checkpoint signal after some constant amount of time (enough time to ensure that the aggregated file would fit into hdfs nicely),   **4)** move to hdfs, **5)** delete the local file.   Step 5 is optional of course :D

Answer (score 2):

Check for [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) and [Apache Flume](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html). You can aggregate logs and move to your data store with them.

I'd use Flume personally. Easier to use imho.

Comment: Didn't use it. But I think it should do the trick [as it seems here](https://github.com/facebook/scribe)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mapreduce there are different ways we can do that

1. Hadoop Archives, or HAR files, are a file archiving facility that packs files into HDFS
   blocks more efficiently, thereby reducing namenode memory usage while still allowing
   transparent access to files
2. The situation is alleviated somewhat by CombineFileInputFormat, which was designed
   to work well with small files. Where FileInputFormat creates a split per file,
   CombineFileInputFormat packs many files into each split so that each mapper has more
   to process. Crucially, CombineFileInputFormat takes node and rack locality into account
   when deciding which blocks to place in the same split, so it does not compromise the
   speed at which it can process the input in a typical MapReduce job.
3. One technique for avoiding the many small files case is to merge small files
   into larger files by using a SequenceFile: the keys can act as filenames (or a constant such as NullWritable, if not needed) and the values as file contents.